# Brand new MVC Asp.Net Project Loads default page, but 403 after for anything else

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I created an ASP.Net MVC project and when I deploy and publish this project the default page will load and appear to work fine, however, if I try to leave to any other URL I get a 403 error. I checked IIS event logs and found this anytime I click a link.

```
> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
> Event time: 5/16/2017 1:46:04 PM  Event time (UTC): 5/16/2017 6:46:04
> PM  Event ID: 9d8a7e9c041b462c9915b24fd7f941db  Event sequence: 8 
> Event occurrence: 2  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>     Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT/test/CC-6-131394337509150873 
>     Trust level: Full 
>     Application Virtual Path: /test/CC 
>     Application Path: D:\zrodelta\dev\test\CC\ 
>     Machine name: JBISVR4    Process information: 
>     Process ID: 156 
>     Process name: w3wp.exe 
>     Account name: IIS APPPOOL\CreditCard    Exception information: 
>     Exception type: HttpException 
>     Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String
> name, String value)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)   
> at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
> 
>     Request information: 
>     Request URL: https://zrodelta.com:443/test/CC/Home/About 
>     Request path: /test/CC/Home/About 
>     User host address: 192.168.125.57 
>     User:  
>     Is authenticated: False 
>     Authentication Type:  
>     Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\CreditCard    Thread information: 
>     Thread ID: 38 
>     Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\CreditCard 
>     Is impersonating: False 
>     Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)   
> at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>     Custom event details:
```

I have not changed any of the defaults and I left everything as the template created. I used Web deploy and everything appears to work. I have heard it has something to do with my routing, or possibly something to do with headers. But I can completely lost.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Uhg.png)

[Page Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZHU5.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck. I have followed most normal steps like assuring permissions, checking framework versions, etc. I feel it is either something in my code, or something I missing on the server, whatever it is, I am sure its a small setting that i need to change, I just don't know what it is. The project is an ASp.Net 4.5.2 project by the way.

After creating new project with no authentication. This still shows up in Event Viewer as the problem:

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 5/16/2017 2:49:10 PM  Event time (UTC): 5/16/2017 7:49:10
>   PM  Event ID: a21d9a3b87f34c8090c7b1e36394c85b  Event sequence: 14 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT/test/CC-3-131394377202796591 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /test/CC 
>       Application Path: D:\zrodelta\dev\test\CC\ 
>       Machine name: JBISVR4    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 1312 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpException 
>       Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String
>   name, String value)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: https://zrodelta.com:443/test/CC/Home/About 
> Request path: /test/CC/Home/About 
> User host address: 192.168.125.57 
> User:  
> Is authenticated: False 
> Authentication Type:  
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 12 
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)    at
> ```
>
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>       Custom event details:

Comment: The message you received seems to imply that you started the project with authentication enabled. Try creating an account and logging in, and then see if you can access the page. Edit: For the type for form you created, authentication might be enabled by default. You can also try to re-create the project without authentication.

Comment: I can't even get to the page to create an account. Once I leave the default load page, I get a 403 error page. I can't move beyond the initial default page loading.

Comment: Go ahead and create a new project, and when you're selecting the type ( like web form, mvc, etc), make sure the radio button on the right hand side has authentication checked off. See if that does the trick. If not, we'll look for another solution

Comment: I am trying that now. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @gavsta707 I did that and I still get a 403 error whenever I leave default load page, which is the Home -> Index. I am starting to think it has to be a server error. Unless something that is default in an MVC project is causing this?

Comment: I am also thinking it is a server issue

Comment: Any ideas? I have never had such a hard time deploying an MVC project. This is like my millionth and this server is fully updated and running 2008 R2 standard.

Comment: Is the azure cloud server thing check marked?

Comment: I don't believe so. Where is that located? I am doing a web deploy to a server here that is our webserver. So I don't think any Azure stuff is happening. Just checked and it was NOT checked.

Comment: I am almost convinced that either the code is adding something to the header, or the server is doing something goofy. But I can't see anything that would be the cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out the issue. With all the solutions online nothing worked, and I finally figured out that it was due to the fact I wanted to hose this site in the same location as a Wordpress site. I did not know this, but Wordpress for SEO friendly URL's has a URL Rewrite function. I added my new folder to an exclusion rule and bam, it all worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should mark your answer as the correct answer :-)